# PIL changed how it converts RGB to L (greyscale)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, grayscale

I have the exact same image processing code running on two different machines inside conda environments, and I expect them both to give identical results, but they don't. So I did a lot of digging and found that the PIL function `Image.convert()` is giving different outputs on the two machines for exactly the same input, which can be explained by the PIL version on one machine being 6.2.1, and on the other machine being 7.0.0.

Looking at the documentation of 6.2.1 and 7.0.0 though, absolutely nothing changed about the formula they use to convert RGB to L in `Image.convert()`. I cloned the git repo and checked the implementation diff and it seems nothing changed:

```
diff --git a/src/libImaging/Convert.c b/src/libImaging/Convert.c
index 60513c66..9f572254 100644
--- a/src/libImaging/Convert.c
+++ b/src/libImaging/Convert.c
@@ -44,7 +44,8 @@
 #define L(rgb)\
     ((INT32) (rgb)[0]*299 + (INT32) (rgb)[1]*587 + (INT32) (rgb)[2]*114)
 #define L24(rgb)\
-    ((rgb)[0]*19595 + (rgb)[1]*38470 + (rgb)[2]*7471)
+    ((rgb)[0]*19595 + (rgb)[1]*38470 + (rgb)[2]*7471 + 0x8000)
+
 
 #ifndef round
 double round(double x) {
```

Note that for my conversion from RGB to L (8-bit), the change in the `L24()` macro above should be irrelevant.

I don't understand where the difference is coming from and would like to understand it. Can anyone with more PIL insight show how/why/where it changed? Is there any note in the documentation that I've missed that this was changed?

Comment: Rechecking `Convert.c` I just noticed that RGB to L does actually indeed use the `L24()` macro, and that it divides by the required 65536 elsewhere in code by simply bit-shifting by 16, thus flooring instead of rounding. Adding `0x8000` then makes this effectively into rounding and is thus more accurate.

Comment: Does that solve the aforementioned problem?

Comment: Yes it seems I found the answer to my own question. The differences in RGB to L conversion I observe between the two stated PIL versions is exactly explained by the changed code line, and the version of the code line in 7.0.0 and later is the more correct version of performing the RGB to L conversion.